# Import .jar libraries in VS Code

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I need to use a .jar library, given by my teacher, to code for my Java class.

I am using VS Code, with the Java Extension Pack installed, for Java Project Management.

**Can someone please explain me step by step how is it possible to import the .jar library, in order to use the classes defined by my teacher.**

I have tried to copy the .jar in the lib folder and then add the reference, but it still did not work. I also know that I have to declare the classpath, but when I create the Java Project the .classpath file is not created automatically.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

First you should examine the classes in .jar file. Then you should load that class as,

```
Class<?> c1 = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```

Then after you can use that class by calling that Class reference type variable.
See this example as well,

```
public class Test { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException { 
    // get the Class instance using forName method 
    Class c1 = Class.forName("java.lang.String"); 

    System.out.print("Class represented by c1: "+ c1.toString()); 
} }
```

Try to understand the code and implement proper solution to your project.
Good Luck.